# date issue with Rest API

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api, iso8601

I am using Jira Rest API. The problem is when I make POST request then I get error:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

After investigating, I came to understand that the problem is with a date format.  When I use the exact date shown below then my request works.

```
2016-11-09T05:28:58.211+0000
```

Can anyone help me determine what exactly is this format -- it looks similar to ISO 8601. I tried the code below but it does not work:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffzfff")
Output: 2016-11-29T01:37:34.453+2453
```

Comment: Umm... Read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)? As it states there: *"fff"
The milliseconds in a date and time value.* and *"zzz"
Hours and minutes offset from UTC.*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just not formatting correctly.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffK")
// "2016-11-28T23:50:06.657+00:00"
```

Note hours need to be `HH`, not `hh`, you shouldn't use `fff` twice, and you should use `K` with `DateTime`, not `z`.

Ideally, ISO8601 extended format should have a colon in the offset, `+00:00` instead of `+0000`.  It is still valid ISO8601 without the colon, but you probably shouldn't omit it unless you're aiming for the ISO8601 *compact* format, which would also remove all dashes and colons from the entire string.

If you really can't handle the colon in the offset, and want the rest to use the extended format, you'll have to remove the one colon manually.

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffK");
s = s.Substring(0, 26) + s.Substring(27,2);
// "2016-11-28T23:50:06.657+0000"
```

As for why you should use `K` instead of something like `zzz` - this comes down to the fact that `DateTime` has a `Kind` property, and `DateTimeOffset` has an offset instead.  More on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier).

Also, keep in mind that you *probably* don't want to use `DateTime.Now` in a REST API.  That API is probably running on a *server*, and the local time zone of the server should be mostly irrelavent to your application, your API, and it's external consumers.  Instead, you probably want to just use `DateTime.UtcNow`, and your output will give a `Z` instead of `+00:00` when you use the `K` specifier.  This is preferred anyway.